Postman - how to validate csv/json test data against API response
I have response in JSON, there are many nested properties inside. How to validate some text or numeric values between csv/json test data file and values in the json response. For example if certain IDs or titles in CSV/JSON complies with JSON body response. I can save JSON response as a global variable, but what to do next??
How to compare CSV data file with associated properties in JSON response?
Let's say I want to validate title value from CSV against following response:
[
        {
            "title": "Rules of Procedure",
            "taxonomyCategoryId": 48984123,
            "taxonomyCategoryName": "Legal documents"
        }
    ]

in post response scripts I have this:
pm.test("Response value matches expected value", function () {
         // this is the element you get from the response
         var jsonData = pm.response.json().title;
         // this is the element coming from the data file
         pm.expect(jsonData.title).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("title"));
 });

CSV test data structured like this:
"title"
"Rules of Procedure"

When running collection with that request and test data csv (same when test data is in JSON format), I'm having this error:
AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'Rules of Procedure'
I believe that there is something wrong with that line of post-script syntax:
pm.expect(jsonData.title).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("title"));

I recommend to split into two questions. It will be easy to get an answer and focus one by one.
You need to provide real JSON example data for validating in first question. The second question , also shows real example data instead of some value only.

Ok, you're right I will post some real examples of my code

Data should never be posted as as image (see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? )

@Thomas: Please verify the column separator in your CSV file (I edited, and did choose a default choice., to show your CSV)

it does not work, same error

@Luuk I tried use json input file and same undefined error occurs, so I think something is wrong with my post-response script syntax:
pm.test("Response value matches expected value", function () {
// this is the element you get from the response
var jsonData = pm.response.json().title;
// this is the element coming from the data file
pm.expect(jsonData.title).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("title"));
});

searching for the error, i do see: Postman API testing: Unable to assert a value is true  Does that help? (I do not have postman installed currently....)

@Luuk ok issue undefined which I have had was due to variable which was defined in two places (environment and collection), removing one from environment fix that, however now I have this error :
AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'Rules of Procedure'
I believe that there is something wrong with that line:
pm.expect(jsonData.title).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("title"));
